# Wordpress Meta Description to add to header file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Yoast installed on my WP site, and every page has the meta description attached to it via Yoast. However if I go into Page Source, none of the pages shows the meta description.

My understanding is that WP by default has stopped adding meta description to the header file. I would like to add the WP tag for meta description to the header file of the site, but am not sure how to do it. I need something like:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php BNOT SURE WHAT TO ADD HERE; ?>">
```

Would appreciate help on this. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link to your website where we can see it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta name="description" content="<? echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true); ?>">
```